# React-Final-Form delays in taking input with render props in Field

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-final-form, final-form

I am currently working on a react project. I am using react-final-form for fetching the data in the form. As I am using the material UI component to create the form I am creating the form somewhat like this.

**Code**

```
 <Form
     onSubmit={onSubmit}
     validate={validate}
     render={({ handleSubmit, values }) => (
         <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl} key={fieldKey}>
                     <Field
                        name={field.fieldName}
                        render={({ input }) => (
                           <TextField
                             {...input}
                             className={classes.textField}
                             variant="outlined"
                             label={props.field.label}
                             placeholder={props.field.description}
                             required={props.field.isMandatory}
                             InputLabelProps={{
                               shrink: true,
                             }}
                          />
                      )}
                      type="text"
                   />
                 </FormControl>
             </form>
          )}
      />
```

Now as soon as I remove the *input* props from the render props it is working fine. but with the input props, it delays in taking input. Without input props, I could not fetch the value from the form.

[image: Exceptions n entering values]

Is there any way to resolve this time delay?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is subscriptions.
The form is initially rendered on every action, react-final-form allows to handle subscription,

```
<Form subscription={{handeleSubmit: true}} ...> </Form>
```

We can do somewhat like this

There is a video link for this. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoSzy-4mviQ&t=1691s)

Hope you find this helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple field. Maybe you can pass on only essential props.

```
<TextField
  name={input.name}
  value={input.value}
  onChange={input.onChange}
/>
```

Comment: No actually I want to use that Teaxfield only. I can't define onChange as there are more than 80 fields!

Comment: Though it did not solve the problem, thanks anyway